# Skinning UI engine for C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, skinning

I have been searching for a way to skin C# applications under Windows Forms. I have yet to find anything that looks or can be made to look, remotely good.

I am looking for something like QT, where you can style your controls with CSS (read this as : has a semi-advanced styling system), but I dont need the advanced controls like gauges and such, plain old Windows Forms controls but that can be styled properly.

My ultimate goal is to have my app look something like Blender 2.5. Specially the menu, blue on black that looks awsome. Every attempt I got in Windows Forms, just looked plain awfull.

A solution with pure image replacements wouldnt be bad either, I can try and photoshop something proper. But styling the same way as in HTML/CSS would work best.

Thank you.
Please keep it constructive.

Comment: What you really want is to use WPF Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound the only problem with using WPF is that it is completely overkill for something as simple as styling default controls properly. It is great to create new complete UI experiences tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Index/themes.xml).  (non-free)
I'm very happy with them.